# Is it possible to enable CORS on AWS CloudFront without S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront CDN to simply cache my static contents in "Origin Pull" mode. The CloudFront origin is my website.

However I've encountered a CORS problem. My browser doesn't let my web pages load my fonts files from CloudFront ... The ironic thing about it is that those fonts were fetched and cached from my website in the first place :(

After googling this matter a bit, I noticed that all blogs/tutorials explain how to enable CORS on an S3 bucket used as the origin for CloudFront, and letting CloudFront forward the `Access-Control-Allow-XXX` headers from S3 to the client.

I don't need an S3 bucket and would like to keep it that way for the sake of simplicity, if possible.

Is it possible to enable CORS on CloudFront ? Even a quick and dirty solution, such as setting the access control header on all responses would be good enough.

Or what other alternatives do I have on CloudFront ? If the easiest other alternative is indeed to use an S3 bucket, what are the drawbacks (modifications to do on my website, service performance, and cost) ?